# welcome message repeated with every message in node js bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am using ADFS authentication for my node js bot, which will be integrated with microsoft teams.

my problem is that, when i signed in bot i got a welcome message-

```
 (session, results, next) => {
      if (session.userData.userName && session.userData.accessToken && session.userData.refreshToken ) {

              builder.Prompts.text(session, "Welcome " + session.userData.userName + "! You are currently logged in into Hotel Bot. Type 'Help' for Bot Help ");

              }

        else {
          session.endConversation("Goodbye.");
        }
      },
```

it is a part of root dialog.

now after this when i am trying to ask any thing to bot this welcome message repeated with every message.
if i comment this prompt then bot stopped responding.

Help me how can i get rid of this repeated message

Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at [Prompt for user input documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt). You can simply use session.send() to send welcome message.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT i saw this one!! but problem is that when user send any command to bot..bot send replies and replace dialog with '/' dialog..so for every question of user bot restart that's why welcome message prompting to user on every chat. if i replace with any other custom dialog except root..then it stopped responding....

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a **first-run dialog** as introduced at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-handle-conversation-events#add-a-first-run-dialog.

The sample following:

```
// Add first run dialog
bot.dialog('firstRun', function (session) {    
    session.userData.firstRun = true;
    session.send("Hello...").endDialog();
}).triggerAction({
    onFindAction: function (context, callback) {
        // Only trigger if we've never seen user before
        if (!context.userData.firstRun) {
            // Return a score of 1.1 to ensure the first run dialog wins
            callback(null, 1.1);
        } else {
            callback(null, 0.0);
        }
    }
});
```

Which leverage a customer variable `firstRun` to check whether the user has come before.  Also you can build your own logic in `onFindAction` event.

Comment: I have multiple session inside my diolog..first is for login second for welcome message and third for checking user response..i want t o run only third session every time..but in current scenario session 2 and 3 running.. I want to run only session 3